# How do I add urls to {% blocktrans %} without failing silently

Tags: django, internationalization

For adding an url to a blocktrans, I use:

```
{% url "home" as home %}
{% blocktrans with url=home %}
...
{% endblocktrans %}
```

However, this is not equivalent to use `{% url "home" %}` without the blocktrans because it fails silently if url `"home"` doesn't exist.

Is there any way to add an url to blocktrans as if I was using `{% url "home" %}` inside the `{% blocktrans %}`?

Putting in other words, how do I make a sentence with an url translatable and having the url not failing silently in Django?